# Matrix environments not being typeset

Tags: math-mode, errors

Why does LaTeX seem to have a problem with the `matrix` environment, and why does it tell me something about `\hbox` badness 10000?

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{karl}
\begin{document}
6) \\
\begin{eqnarray} 
a_1=a_1*b_1& \\
a_2=a_1*b_2&+a_2*b_3\\
a_3=a_3*b_3&
\end{eqnarray} 
\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
1
\end{matrix}
\begin{eqnarray}
b_1=a_1*b_1& \\
b_2=a_1*b_2&+a_2*b_3\\
b_3=a_3*b_3&
\end{eqnarray}
bei festem b liefert Koefizientenvergleich für a die Triviallösung
\begin{matrix}
 1 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 1
\end{matrix}
Somit gibt es für beide Seiten das gleiche Element was auf der Identität abbildet, somit ist
\begin{matrix}
 1 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 1
\end{matrix}
 auch das neutrale Element \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `latex` program, your compiler, can be your friend. It's giving you helpful hints.

Answer (score 6):

The `matrix` environments need to be placed in math mode. For that, either use `$\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}$`, or `\[\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}\]`. The former is an in-line math expression, while the latter is a display math environment.

The `\hbox` badness stems from lines that are too wide to fit within the text block margins, or when you're using inappropriate line-breaking techniques. The latter case occurs when you issue

```
6) \\
<more stuff>
```

It's better to remove the `\\` and leave a blank line between the content. This will be similar to a regular paragraph break. If you plan on enumerating content, consider using an `enumerate` list.

Other suggestions:

- Use `\times` instead of `*` to represent multiplication (or drop it altogether, since it makes sense within a mathematical context); and
- Use `align`-and-friends instead of `eqnarray` (see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764))